# Generate list of random Characters while keeping the seed

Tags: haskell

My goal is to write a function that generates a random string of characters (alphanumeric) of a given length based on a seed. Important is that the result is not only the string but also the new seed.

I know I can get a String by using take on randomRS but the problem is I wouldn't be able to retrieve the seed afterwards

```
generate :: StdGen -> String -> (String, StdGen)
```

I was able to write it for one character although I couldn't not get the range to allow both letters and numbers

```
generateRandomCharacter gen = randomR ('a','z') gen
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to define the available characters you are interested in as an array and then randomly select characters from the array.

```
randomEl :: RandomGen g => [a] -> g -> (a, g)
randomEl xs g -> (g', xs !! r) 
  where (r, g') = randomR (0, length xs - 1) g

randomAlphaNum :: RandomGen g => g -> (Char, g)
randomAlphaNum = randomEl (['0'..'9'] ++ ['a'..'z'])
```

Next building the string should be pretty easy... There is for example the  [iterate](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:iterate) defined in Prelude.

```
generate :: RandomGen g => Int -> g -> (String, g)
generate n g = (map fst iterations, (snd . last) iterations)
  where iterations = (take n . iterate (randomAlphaNum . snd)) (randomAlphaNum g)
```

Comment: That's a list, not an array. Looking things up in it will be slow.

Answer (score 3):

The best technique is to use "split":

```
class RandomGen g where
    split :: g -> (g,g)
    -- Other functions as well.
```

Split your random generator in two. Use one of the results to generate your random string, and return the other one with the result.

Its not clear from your question how long the string should be: presumably it should be the same length as the input string. If so then it would be better style to take an Int length as the argument.

You also say you haven't figured out how to select from a more complicated range than just ('a', 'z'). You need to set up an array (or better yet, a vector) of candidate items and choose one from that. You could use a list, but that means you will be iterating through the list every time.

Answer (score 3):

Paul Johnson's seed splitting approach is certainly reasonable, but since you're producing a string of known length, another good option is to use `replicateM` within a randomness monad.

```
generateR :: (MonadRandom m, Random a) => Int -> (a, a) -> m [a]
generateR len range = replicateM len (getRandomR range)
```